# Normal Probability Distributin

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Given a normal distribution with mean = 82 and standard deviation = 25  , Find the probability that X assumes a value ?

A. Less than 78 = (Correct Answer: 0.2119) (My Answer : 0.4364)

Why the hell im wrong I convert the value of X to Z using x-mean/standard deviation = -0.16 which is the value of 0.4364 in Z table

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me. Maybe there is a misprint in the solution, or possibly you're misreading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed
$$
\Phi \left(\frac{78-82}{25} \right) = \Phi(-0.16) \approx 0.4364
$$
but
$$
\Phi \left(\frac{78-82}{\sqrt{25}} \right) = \Phi(-0.8) \approx 0.2119
$$
Maybe the variance and standard deviation got mixed up.